# Yii2 Deleting via hyperlink in gridview from frontend via backend model gives Bad Request (#400)

Tags: gridview, yii2, frontend, backend, bad-request

I have an update form for a table called features and have put a gridview::widget on it to deal with associated images.  I can update the images via the update button, but when I try to delete I get the bad request message.

My code generates the following code for the gridview delete icon:

```
<a href="http://gb.n/image/delete/16" 
   title="Delete" 
   aria-label="Delete" 
   data-confirm="Are you sure that you want to delete this image??"          
   data-method="post" data-pjax="0">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>    
</a>
```

The "feature" form is on the frontend and the image mvc is on the backend of my "advanced" template implementation.

Having looked for the solution, I suspect that it is something to do with cookies, but as I'm new to Yii and MVC frameworks, it might be anything.

My environment is on Win 7, Apache 2.4.4.

More info as requested:

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'defaultRoute' => 'pages/index',
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => ['class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
//            // Disable index.php 
            'showScriptName' => FALSE,
//            // Disable r= routes 
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+\-\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<slug:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => '<controller>/view',
            ],
        ],
        //can name it whatever you want as it is custom
        'urlManagerBackend' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => 'http://gb.n',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,  
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

The actionDelete method from ImageController:

```
public function actionDelete($id) {

        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        try {

            unlink($model->image_path);

            unlink($model->thumb_path);

            unlink($model->mobile_path);

            $model->delete();

            return $this->redirect(['index']);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            throw new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I've added this to the ImageController.  I found it elsewhere on stack overflow:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    if ($action->id == 'delete') {
        Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: How you (your link) refer to backend ?? I can't understand form your link ...

Comment: Hello scaisEdge, thanks for asking.

Comment: Hi scaisEdge.  The link in on a frontend page, and I used Html::a with the url created like so: `Yii::$app->urlManagerBackend->baseUrl . '/image/delete/' . $model->id`   Thanks.

Comment: Have a check at the CSRF settings!  That may solve your problem.

Comment: Try disabling csrf in your controller action and see.

Comment: Show your related backend controller action (Seems you have a ImageController in backend) and also the config/main.php urlManager..

Comment: I have now disabled the csrf in the controller action for delete only and am trying to pass a variable through to limit it to deletes called from the feature update form from which I'm sending the delete request.

Comment: And I've added to the code above to show this.